# Pseudocode - What is wrong about this

Tags: pseudocode

I AM TRYING TO FIND THE ERROR

The code is supposed to find out if a positive integer entered by a user is exactly divisible by the number 3.

```
n = userinput
WHILE n ≥ 0
  n = n - 3
ENDWHILE
```

Comment: Are you asking solely about pseudocode or did you try to translate this into Python?

Comment: If `n` is zero in your while loop, it'll subtract 3 again, so `n` will never be zero, thus the `IF n = 0` will never be true.

Comment: Have you actually stepped through this with paper and pencil?

Comment: what's wrong with n % 3 != 0  ?

Comment: I suspect this is a homework question where the assignment was to explain the logic, not so much an actual attempt at programming an explicit version of the `%` operator

Comment: yep, I have been told to find the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using greater than OR EQUAL TO so you won't break out of the loop on n = 0, only n = -3 which then triggers your ELSE statement. The EQUAL TO aspect takes you a step too far.

Answering the comment:
Use > instead of >=. Basically the code as written will never allow n to equal 0 at the time the condition is evaluated. Trace each step of the loop using a number like 3.

```
N = 3
//first pass
WHILE (3 >= 0) // true
n = 3-3 //n now 0

//second pass
WHILE (0 >= 0) //True, 0 is equal to 0
n = 0-3 //n now -3

//third pass
WHILE(-3 >= 0) //False break out of loop

IF(-3 == 0) // false so we jump to the else

ELSE: 3 is not divisible by 3.
```

One quick way to easily spot check your loops that aren't performing as expected is to just manually run through them with an easy input.

Comment: I added a step by step explanation of the process. Remember the great thing about computers is that they do exactly what you tell them. Also remember the worst thing about computers is that they do EXACTLY what you tell them.